# Pixel Co-Ordinate Logging for an imported Image (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, opencv, coordinates, calibration

Okay so, I want to be able to record the co-ordinates of pixels within a given image. The image is used to calibrate and determine the lens distortion and iFoV (Field of View) of a camera at varying distances.

I am trying to code (in Python) a program that will allow me to open up an initial image within a directory and allow me to pinpoint the pixel co-ordinates of the following areas;

TOP LEFT, TOP RIGHT, TOP MIDDLE, MID RIGHT, MID LEFT, BOT LEFT, BOT MID and BOT RIGHT

So basically, i need to open the image click those 8 points (recording the points in a csv file) then press a key e.g. ''SPACEBAR'' or ''ESC'' etc. which brings up the next image in the directory (Tool at a new length). Being able to repeat for many images.

Example Calibration Tool - Red Dots are the Wanted Co-Ordinates:

[image: Example Calibration Tool - Red Dots are the Wanted Co-Ordinates]

Answer (score 0):

I have written a mock tool that addresses your purpose.

- Pass the appropriate path conatining image in `filepath`.
- Press and release left mouse button to see the marking.
- Hit spacebar to clear markings on current image (in case you make a mistake).
- Press lower case 'q' to move to next image.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

ix, iy = -1, -1

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy, mode

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        print(x, y)

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

filepath = r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\*.png'   
for file in glob.glob(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    img2 = img.copy()

    while(1):
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == 32:                    #--- Press spacebar to clear markings on current image ---
            img = img2.copy()
        elif k == ord('q'):            #--- Press lowercase q to move to next image ---
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Appreciate it, will get back to you once I test it